# nginx Failing to Serve Static Files to Flask

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, gunicorn, flask

I've tried numerous solutions of other posts, but nothing seems to work for me, I always get a 404 error, when trying to let **nginx** serve static files of my **flask** application. On my local host server, flask is unable to receive static files from another internal software static directory.

I am running a gunicorn server at **localhost:7777** and receive the following errors when attempting to run one of the pages on my web page:

```
127.0.0.1/:210     GET http://127.0.0.1:7777/Website/visualization/static/js/main.3a9af0a7.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

manifest.json:1     GET http://127.0.0.1:7777/Website/visualization/manifest.json 404 (NOT FOUND)

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  file has the block that is supposed to serve the files above to flask:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
        
    access_log /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/nginx-error.log;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        
        location ~ ^/Website/visualization/reference/(\S+)$ {
            alias /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse/reference/$1;
        }

        location ~ /visualization/5c9f1639441ae475a829.worker.js {
            alias /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse/5c9f1639441ae475a829.worker.js;
        }

        location ~ /visualization/manifest.json {
            alias /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse/manifest.json;
        }
        
        location ~ /visualization/config.json {
            alias /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse/config.json;
        }
        
        location /Website/visualization/static/ {
            alias /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse/static/;
        }

        location /Website/visualization/vcf/{
            alias /home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse/vcf/;
        }
        
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
   }
```

my **app.py** is located `/home/antho/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web` with the remaining files for the website.

I have made sure all files have the correct permissions, I gave the files all the perms I can give just to make sure:

```
antho@x005:~/Website_Stack/server/opt/web/sc_web/templates/JBrowse$ ls -l
total 17672
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx  3254625 Aug 22 01:29 5c9f1639441ae475a829.worker.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx    12889 Aug 22 01:29 5c9f1639441ae475a829.worker.js.LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx 11890441 Aug 22 01:29 5c9f1639441ae475a829.worker.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx     1949 Aug 22 01:29 asset-manifest.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx   378219 Aug 22 01:29 config.DB_V1.0.1.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx   386923 Aug 22 01:29 config.DB_V1.0.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx   644276 Aug 22 01:29 config.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx   418838 Aug 22 01:29 config.V1.1.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx   393995 Aug 22 01:29 config.V1.1.old.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx   617012 Aug 22 01:29 config.V1.2.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx    15086 Aug 22 01:29 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx     8167 Sep 28 16:34 index_bak.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx     8063 Sep 28 16:40 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx      294 Sep 27 09:58 manifest.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx       27 Sep 28 14:35 package-lock.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx     3521 Aug 22 01:29 precache-manifest.821b6df26bf08d62dbdfb33a979d34ae.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 nginx nginx     4096 Aug 22 01:30 reference
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx       57 Aug 22 01:30 robots.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx     1185 Aug 22 01:30 service-worker.js
drwxrwxrwx 5 nginx nginx     4096 Aug 22 01:30 static
drwxrwxrwx 7 nginx nginx     4096 Aug 22 01:30 test_data
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx       45 Oct  6 13:47 test.html
drwxrwxrwx 4 nginx nginx     4096 Aug 22 01:31 vcf
```

The nginx error and access logs do not give any information.

I have tried many solutions for fixing the paths to the static files, using both root and alias options, but have not had any luck fixing this issue. All instances of "Website" are a standin name for the actual website.

This is my first attempt at software development and have starting to run out of ideas to try. Let me know if there is anything I should add for context.

Thanks for any help!

Best,
Anthony Shea.

Comment: `I have tried many solutions for fixing the paths to the static files` I am unable to observe any attempts or solutions, nor any log entries indicating failed attempts. Please check and verify [ask] to read it carefully step by step and then update your question. The current state makes it a decent start, but it needs a more polished end. ;-)